# Python script acting differently when called from PHP opposed to from the terminal

Tags: php, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

So my python3 script works when I run it from the terminal but not when I call it from a php script (just using exec and I literally type the same things in the terminal command).

The script does run, but certain things makes it error (I don't know how to get the error messages, just the exit code -- 0 or 1). Firstly, string concatenation (using string1 + string2) didn't work, so I had to use % placeholders.

And the problem I'm currently trying to solve is url request. I've tried using

`requests.get(url)`

and

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Both of them work from terminal and the php script will work/wont error when they are commented out. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

**Edit**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./scripts/getSBNews.py", line 49, in getSBNews
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: you must search for the errors logged on your server, maybe if you are using apache on linux, they are available on /var/log/apache2/access.log, however, you can find the logs directory thanks to a quick search "default logs directory of XXX server" I hink your problems comes because executing requests like you are doing can cause security problems, but I'm not sure. Please give us your logs if you don't find what's the issue

Comment: Oh smart! So it looks like its a bad request